# I am getting one error while using the mgtwitter engine my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting the error for using the NSImage in this function in my appcontroller
like expected ')' before NSImage.

```
- (void)imageReceived:(NSImage *)image forRequest:(NSString *)identifier
{

    NSString *path = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/Desktop/%@.tiff", identifier] 
                      stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

   [[image TIFFRepresentation] writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
}
```

i have check  my program  i got no syntax error but still i have this error in my app.
i have taken the code from mgtwitterengine and using it for iphone in my app as given in its read me file.

Comment: First thing I noticed is that you're trying to write a file to the Desktop, which doesn't exist in iPhone OS. Other than that, I'm not really sure what your error message is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`NSImage`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is not available on the iPhone since it is part of the AppKit framework in Cocoa. You will need to deal with [`UIImage`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead, which is from the UIKit framework in Cocoa Touch.